# I have 6 div tags nested in a div tag how do I use beautiful soup nd parse this result in 6 different columns with pandas a sample image is given pls

Tags: python, pandas

Sample Image of what I want
[image]

I have tried

```py
    import re from bs4
    import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    
    file = "<body><table class="gb-widget-data_table ext-widget-data_table ext-widget-data_table-striped">
        <tbody>
        <tr class="gb-widget-data_table_row_header ext-widget-data_table_row_header">
            <td class="gb-widget-data_table_row_column_header ext-widget-data_table_row_column_header">ID</td>
            <td class="gb-widget-data_table_row_column_header ext-widget-data_table_row_column_header">Date/Time</td>
            <td class="gb-widget-data_table_row_column_header ext-widget-data_table_row_column_header">Results</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="gb-widget-data_table_row ext-widget-data_table_row">
            <td class="gb-widget-data_table_row_column ext-widget-data_table_row_column">16213393</td>
            <td class="gb-widget-data_table_row_column ext-widget-data_table_row_column">03/07/2021 10:20</td>
            <td class="gb-widget-data_table_row_column ext-widget-data_table_row_column gb-widget-data_table_row_column-small-paddings">
                <div>
                    <div class="gb-widget-icon_container ext-widget-icon_container gb-widget-icon_container--small gb-widget-color_color-blue_ball">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="gb-widget-icon_container ext-widget-icon_container gb-widget-icon_container--small gb-widget-color_color-yellow_ball">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class="gb-widget-icon_container ext-widget-icon_container gb-widget-icon_container--small gb-widget-color_color-yellow_ball">
                        8
                    </div>
                    <div class="gb-widget-icon_container ext-widget-icon_container gb-widget-icon_container--small gb-widget-color_color-yellow_ball">
                        20
                    </div>
                    <div class="gb-widget-icon_container ext-widget-icon_container gb-widget-icon_container--small gb-widget-color_color-yellow_ball">
                        35
                    </div>
                    <div class="gb-widget-icon_container ext-widget-icon_container gb-widget-icon_container--small gb-widget-color_color-red_ball">
                        10
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table></body>"
        soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')
    
    match = soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('^gb-widget-icon_container ext-widget-icon_container gb-widget-icon_container--small gb-widget-color_color-'))
    match = soup.div
    okays = match.find('div', class_=re.compile('^gb-widget-icon_container ext-widget-icon_container gb-widget-icon_container--small gb-widget-color_color-'))
    
    print(okays)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way, starting from your `match` line. You can piece the rest of the columns in to fill out your dataframe.

```
   match = soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('^gb-widget-icon_container ext-widget-icon_container gb-widget-icon_container--small gb-widget-color_color-'))
    res = []
    for m in match:
        # print(m.text.strip())
        res.append([m.text.strip()])
    
    cols=['Results1','Results2','Results3','Results4','Results5','Results6']
    pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(cols,res)))
```

Output:

```
  Results1 Results2 Results3 Results4 Results5 Results6
0        3        2        8       20       35       10
```

Comment: Thanks alot bro I really do appreciate

Comment: Glad to help. If you can accept the answer that'd be great

Comment: I have they say I need at least 15 reputation I just joined stack overflow because of this problem I had

Comment: How do I gain the 15 reputation though?